# How to implement business rules at each node in a self hierarchical tree structure

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, design-patterns

In a self hierarchical tree like structure, I would like to check for business rules(based on node type) at each node level on every node addition/edition/deletion. I tried implementing composite design pattern but no luck. Please suggest.

Sample class structure.

```
class Parent
{
    int Id;
}

class ChildType1 : Parent
{
    string propForType1;
    List<Parent> ListOfChildren;
}

class ChildType2 : Parent
{
    string propForType2;
    List<Parent> ListOfChildren;
}
```

[image]

When I say business rules, it means those rules are specific constraints for node type.
For ex: Business rule 1 - ChildType2 can have only children of type ChildType2
Business rule 2 - ChildType1 should have atleast 2 child nodes and propForType1 values should not be empty.

For every new node addition/edition/deletion I need to check these rules at each node, so that my overall tree satisfies all the business rules.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Provide an example of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the visitor pattern.  Its sweet spot is working with trees/collections of data where the children are implementations of a base class.

A good article from Uncle Bob can be found here: http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.IuseVisitor

Another reference can be found here:
http://www.dofactory.com/net/visitor-design-pattern

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of adding a validation method that you can call, and overriding it and creating implementations per type.

```
class Parent
{
    int Id;
    public abstract bool isValid();
}

class ChildType1 : Parent
{
    string propForType1;
    List<Parent> ListOfChildren;
    public override bool isValid() {
        return ListOfChildren.Count >= 2;
    }
}

class ChildType2 : Parent
{
    string propForType2;
    List<Parent> ListOfChildren;
    public override bool isValid() {
        foreach (Parent p in ListOfChildren) {
            if (!(p is ChildType2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And maybe call isValid() during the add/edit/delete?